# Concatenate names of the columns in a dataframe which contain true

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
|id|type|isBlack|isHigh|isLong|  
|1 |A   |true   |false |null  |  
|2 |B   |true   |true  |true  |  
|3 |C   |false  |null  |null  |
```

I'm trying to concatenate names of columns which contain 'true' into another column to get this:

```
|id|type|isBlack|isHigh|isLong|Description          |
|1 |A   |true   |false |null  |isBlack              |
|2 |B   |true   |true  |true  |isBlack,isHigh,isLong|
|3 |C   |false  |null  |null  |null                 |
```

Now, I have a predefined list of column names that I need to check for (in this example it'd be Seq("isBlack", "isHigh", "isLong"), which are present in the dataframe (this list can be somewhat long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val cols = Seq("isBlack", "isHigh", "isLong")

df.withColumn("description", concat_ws(",", cols.map(x => when(col(x), x)): _*)).show(false)
+---+----+-------+------+------+---------------------+
|id |type|isBlack|isHigh|isLong|description          |
+---+----+-------+------+------+---------------------+
|1  |A   |true   |false |null  |isBlack              |
|2  |B   |true   |true  |true  |isBlack,isHigh,isLong|
|3  |C   |false  |null  |null  |                     |
+---+----+-------+------+------+---------------------+
```

Firstly `map` columns to column names when the value is `true` with:

```
cols.map(x => when(col(x), x))
```

And then use `concat_ws` to combine the columns `concat_ws(",", cols.map(x => when(col(x), x)): _*)`